# How to generate screenshot from stored HTML as a string?

Tags: selenium, webkit, webdriver, screenshot

Is it possible to generate a screenshot from a saved HTML string?

(more specifically, I mean very simple pages)

I know there are a lot of webkit based libraries around that generate screenshots but they all seem to expect a URL. What if the HTML content is stored or in a variable?

I'd prefer Python but I'm open to any other solutions.

Comment: A screenshot of the string in plaintext? Or do you mean you want to render the string _as html_ and then screenshot that?

Answer (score 2):

yes, in java there is a awt control that can do this. you can pass the content of html string and it can generate screenshot.

this is one of a similiar type:

http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/